Uploading ontology to Stardog
I'm trying to upload the ontology to Stardog and i got this error:

Failed to load data to "catalog": There was a fatal failure during
preparation of f0eadb93-b65b-4d4b-9a85-243e969ca1e2:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://api.stardog.com/;
lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 15; Element or attribute do not match
QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName. [L5:15]

Any idea?
I want to solve this issue. Here is the snap of code:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:1.0="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT/1.0#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:ssn="http://www.w3.org/ns/ssn/"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:bibo="http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/"
     xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
     xmlns:sosa="http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/"
     xmlns:vaem="http://www.linkedmodel.org/schema/vaem#"
     xmlns:vann="http://purl.org/vocab/vann/"
     xmlns:terms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
     xmlns:parrot="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT#"
     xmlns:schema="http://schema.org/"
     xmlns:gdprtext="https://w3id.org/GDPRtEXT#"
     xmlns:iot-lite="http://purl.oclc.org/NET/UNIS/fiware/iot-lite#"
     xmlns:wgs84_pos="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT">
        <owl:versionIRI rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT/PbD"/>
        <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://purl.oclc.org/NET/UNIS/fiware/iot-lite#"/>
        <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core"/>
        <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/"/>
        <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/ns/ssn/"/>
        <owl:imports rdf:resource="https://w3id.org/GDPRtEXT/v/0.7"/>
    </owl:Ontology>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT#entails -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT#entails">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#topObjectProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain>
            <owl:Class>
                <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT#Access_Data"/>
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT#Device"/>
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/Sensor"/>
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://w3id.org/GDPRtEXT#Activity"/>
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://w3id.org/GDPRtEXT#DataActivity"/>
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://w3id.org/GDPRtEXT#IdentificationOfDataSubject"/>
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://w3id.org/GDPRtEXT#PersonalData"/>
                </owl:unionOf>
            </owl:Class>
        </rdfs:domain>
        <rdfs:range>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT#entails"/>
                <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT#Privacy_Pattern"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:range>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">The relationship between system components or activities with the privacy patterns.</rdfs:comment>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>

This is Parrot ontology:https://github.com/alkharijiLa/PARROT/blob/main/PARROT.rdf

Sounds like a problem with the file you're uploading; it's going to be hard for anyone to guess the problem without a sample of the file.

Many thanks for the comments. Here is the line that is exactly about the error, although the reasoner does not give me an error. It makes me confused: xmlns:1.0="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT/1.0#".

Please can you click [edit] and add a small sample of the XML, escaped using the code sample syntax ({} button on the edit toolbar).

I did it, is the error clear now?

Your XML is not valid; specifically this attribute:
xmlns:1.0="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT/1.0#"

As discussed on this question, an xmlns attribute defines a "namespace prefix", which gives special meaning to tags in the document beginning with that prefix.
The prefix name follows the same rules as normal XML tag names, which means it is not allowed to start with a digit.
In the sample you've shown, there aren't actually any tags prefixed 1.0:, so you may be able to just remove it as unused. However, if there are in the full document, you just need to pick a different prefix. For example:
xmlns:parrot_1_0="http://www.semanticweb.org/c1881660/ontologies/PARROT/1.0#"

Then replace it throughout, e.g. <1.0:something>example/<1.0:something> with <parrot_1_0:something>example</parrot_1_0:something>
